# Events not firing on before filters in a standalone Illuminate 4.1 stack

Tags: php, laravel

The past days I've been attempting to get up and running a fully function API with JWT support based on Illuminate 4.1 packages.

The current stack includes:

- events
- routing
- cache
- database
- config
- auth

And for JWT I'm using a modified version of tymon/jwt-auth 0.4 (only modification is downgrading array syntax to pre-PHP 5.4 and Closure changes to ommit $this)

So far I've gotten everything mostly working: The routing works, config works, Container works and all but I seem to be struggling to get the routing `before` filters working. The issue is that the before filter gets "ignored". Using a test route, it responds with the output of the controller instead of giving a reply, that the token is missing or similar.

Following the tymon/jwt-auth setup wiki, I have created a routing group which uses the `jwt-auth` filter in my routes.php

```js
<?php

/** @var \Illuminate\Routing\Router $router */
$router = $app['router'];

$router->post('/auth', 'MyApp\Api\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@authenticate');

$router->group(array('before' => 'jwt-auth'), function (\Illuminate\Routing\Router $router) {
    $router->post('/authed', 'MyApp\Api\Controllers\HelloController@loggedIn');
});
```

I also tested by manually parsing the token by doing `JWTAuth::parseToken()->toUser()` and that worked perfectly so I've isolated the issue to the `before` filter.

I walked through the stack on how `before` filters are handled and I reached the part where it fires and event in the events Dispatcher. My theory on this is that it either isn't firing the event or some listener isn't reacting like it should.

As a test subject, I created a Laravel 4.1 app with original tymon/jwt-auth 0.4. I set up everything similarly and there the `before` filter works like it should.

As a reference, here is my entire Illuminate-stack API bootstrapper (public/index.php)

```js
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json');

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, HEAD');

require_once(__DIR__ . '/../../../vendor/autoload.php');
require_once(__DIR__ . '/../../../vendor/illuminate/support/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php');

use Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Config\FileLoader;
use Illuminate\Config\Repository;
use Illuminate\Container\Container;
use Illuminate\Events\EventServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem;
use Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Routing\RoutingServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\ClassLoader;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\JWTAuthServiceProvider;

$configDir = __DIR__ . '/../config';
$controllersDir = __DIR__ . '/../src/Controllers';
$modelsDir = __DIR__ . '/../../../models';

ClassLoader::register();
ClassLoader::addDirectories(array($controllersDir, $modelsDir));

$app = new Container;
Facade::setFacadeApplication($app);

$app['app'] = $app;

$app['env'] = env('APP_ENVIRONMENT');

$loader = new FileLoader(new Filesystem, $configDir);
$config = new Repository($loader, 'production');

$app['config'] = $config;

$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$app['request'] = $request;

with(new EventServiceProvider($app))->register();
with(new CacheServiceProvider($app))->register();
with(new RoutingServiceProvider($app))->register();
with(new FilesystemServiceProvider($app))->register();
with(new AuthServiceProvider($app))->register();
with(new JWTAuthServiceProvider($app))->register();

require(__DIR__ . '/../src/routes.php');

try {
    $response = $app['router']->dispatch($request);
} catch (\Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException $e) {
    $response = new JsonResponse(array(
        'status_code' => $e->getStatusCode(),
        'message' => $e->getMessage()
    ), $e->getStatusCode());
} catch (\Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenInvalidException $e) {
    $response = new JsonResponse(array(
        'status_code' => $e->getStatusCode(),
        'message' => $e->getMessage()
    ), $e->getStatusCode());
} catch (\Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException $e) {
    $response = new JsonResponse(array(
        'status_code' => $e->getStatusCode(),
        'message' => $e->getMessage()
    ), $e->getStatusCode());
} catch (\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException $e) {
    $response = new JsonResponse(array(
        'status_code' => JsonResponse::HTTP_NOT_FOUND,
        'message' => 'Route not found'
    ), JsonResponse::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
} catch (\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException $e) {
    $response = new JsonResponse(array(
        'status_code' => JsonResponse::HTTP_FORBIDDEN,
        'message' => 'Method not allowed'
    ), JsonResponse::HTTP_FORBIDDEN);
}

$response->send();
```

Could anyone give me some pointers on how to get the before filter to work?
Could it be related to service provider registering?
Could I be missing something to successfully fire events?
Could I be missing some default event listener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure in 100% but it looks like you've missed `boot()` step for registered providers.

`jwt-auth` package provider is registering a filter in `boot()` method:

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->package('tymon/jwt-auth', 'jwt', __DIR__.'/../');
    $this->bootBindings();
    // register the command
    $this->commands('tymon.jwt.generate');
    // register the filter
    $this->app['router']->filter('jwt-auth', 'tymon.jwt.filter');
}
```

I'd say that before calling `register()` method of `JWTAuthServiceProvider` you should also call `boot()` method.

Comment: Haha, you have saved me. I had to initiate `boot()` after registering the service provider. Also had to assing `path` to the app Container as well. But with those changes in place, the before filter is working. Thank-you very much for helping me find the issue on this. I will award you the bounty in 21 hours :)

Comment: Glad I could help you :)

I'd suggest running `boot()` before `register()`. It's the order in which Laravel handles service providers.